# Problems about java syntax

Tags: jvm, java

Here's the code :

```
public class EmployeeTest
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    //System.out.println("hello world");

    Employee aEmployee = new Employee("David",1000);
    System.out.println(aEmployee.getName() + aEmployee.getSalary());
    }
}

class Employee // **why can't I put a "public" here**
{
    // Constructor
    public Employee(String name, double salary)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    // Methods
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public double getSalary()
    {
        return this.salary;
    }

    // instance field
    private String name;
    private double salary;
}
```

My question is : in the second class definition's first line, why can't I put a "**public**" to define it ?
What's the exactly meaning of "public" when using it defines a class ?

Comment: You can put a public there if it's in a file called Employee.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is language feature. There must be only one `top-level` public class per .java file and public class name must *match* the source java file name.

Basically, *non-public* types are not accessible outside the *package* so if you wish to allow type to be used anywhere then make it *public*.

Never create a type in default package. ([Always use package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html))

Employee.java

---

```
package com.abc.model;

public class Employee{..}
```

EmployeeTest.java

---

```
package com.abc.test;

public class EmployeeTest{ ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because a Java source file can have at most one top-level `public` class or interface, and the name of the source file must be the same as the name of that class or interface.

That's a rule that the Java compiler of Oracle's JDK imposes.

Comment: Can you please prove evidence for the "at most one" part? Ive searched the spec over and over and havent found such restriction. Besides that `Employee` is a top-level class unaffected whether its public or not.

Comment: A source file can have zero or one top-level `public` class or interface. It's not part of the language spec (it's not a language feature as AVD says); it's a restriction in Oracle's Java compiler.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, there can only be a single *public* top level class per source file and it needs to be named the same as the file.

This is useful for the compiler when it needs to locate a class definition from outside the package, since it knows the type name, it knows which class file to find the class in. For example. since a jar file is in essence a zip file with class files, this prevents the compiler from having to unzip the entire jar to find a class definition.

The [Java language specification §7.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6) specifies this as an optional restriction;

> If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host
>   system may choose to enforce the restriction that *it is a compile-time
>   error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the
>   type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the
>   following is true:*
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the
>     package in which the type is declared.
> - *The type is declared public (and therefore is potentially accessible
>     from code in other packages).*

Answer (score 0):

you can define a public class inside a public class which is legal.

```
public class EmployeeTest
{
     public class Employee {

     }
}
```

Comment: @joshz, yes you can do like this

Comment: Well that is not going to work in his specific case. The inner class must be `static`.